# how to open a jquery defined link in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, tabs, window

How do I open this link to open in a new tab. None of the other question asked seem to specify how to mesh this with the target of the link being defined in the JS file. Please help!

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p><span id="popUpMoreLink">Contact Me</span></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#popUpMoreLink').click(function () {
    window.location = 'mailto:exmpl@gmail.com?Subject=Inquiry';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

window.open() will fire up a new window.

```
$('#popUpMoreLink').click(function () {
    window.open('mailto:exmpl@gmail.com?Subject=Inquiry');
});
```

but since the link is a "mailto:" (it opens thunderbird / outlook / whatever mail client is installed on the client's system) I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: LOL ty i just found it

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried window.open('mailto:')?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Instead of

> window.location

it is

> window.**open**

```
$(function(){
  $('#popUpMoreLink').click(function() {
    window.open('mailto:exmpl@gmail.com?Subject=Inquiry');
  });
});
```